# sets in python problem

Tags: python, set

can we remove a entry from the sets.

what are the commands to use for it?

like, my set conatins (6,5) , (6,7), (7,9)...I need to remove the second entry...what shud I do??

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html has the answer.  Why ask here?

Comment: I know this is in poor taste, but 16 questions in 11 days?  Can't you solve any problems on your own?  A quick look at the official python documentation would have provided the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_set.remove((6, 7))
```

The `remove()` method can be used to remove items from a set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.remove):

```
>>> s = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> s.remove(2)
>>> s
set([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

a -= set([(6, 7)])

:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a list of those tuples you can clear it out like this:

```
l = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
l.remove((3,4))
[(1, 2), (5, 6)]
```